# Gstreamer does not produce audio when imported from a homebrew module

Tags: python, oop, module, gstreamer

Just for fun, I've been using `python` and `gstreamer` to create simple Linux audio players. The first one was a command-line procedural script that used gst-launch-0.10 playbin to play a webstream. The second version was again procedural but had a GUI and used playbin2 to create the gstreamer pipeline. Now I'm trying to create a fully OOP version.

My first step was to put the gstreamer code in a module of its own and save it as 'player.py':

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

"""player.py"""

import glib, pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst

class Player():
  def __init__(self):
    self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline("myPipeline")
    self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin2", "theplayer")
    self.pipeline.add(self.player)
    self.audiosink = gst.element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", 'audiosink')
    self.audiosink.set_property('async-handling', True)
    self.player.set_property("uri", "http://sc.grupodial.net:8086")
    self.pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Player()
  glib.MainLoop().run()
```

(Please note that this is a very simple experimental script that automatically loads and plays a stream. In the final application there will be specific methods of Player to take care of URI/file selection and play/pause/stop reproduction.)

The file was marked as executable and the following command made it run fine, the webstream being loaded and played:

```
$ python player.py
```

However, trying to run it directly (using the shebang directive) returned

```
$ ./player.py
: No such file or directory
```

Anyway, having made it work as a standalone script I wrote the following "main" application code to import the player module and create an instance of Player:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

"""jukebox3.py"""

import glib
import player

def main():
  myplayer = player.Player()

  # remove these later:
  print myplayer.pipeline
  print myplayer.player
  print myplayer.audiosink
  print myplayer.player.get_property("uri")
  print myplayer.pipeline.get_state()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
  glib.MainLoop().run()
```

Running this main script either through the interpreter or directly produces **no sound at all** though I believe the instance is created because the printing statements output information consistent with playbin2 behavior:

```
/GstPipeline:myPipeline (gst.Pipeline)
/GstPipeline:myPipeline/GstPlayBin2:theplayer (__main__.GstPlayBin2)
/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink (__main__.GstAutoAudioSink)
http://sc.grupodial.net:8086
(<enum GST_STATE_CHANGE_SUCCESS of type GstStateChangeReturn>, <enum GST_STATE_PLAYING of type GstState>, <enum GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING of type GstState>)
```

BTW, the result is the same using either `glib.MainLoop` or `gtk.main` to create the main loop.

Any suggestions what am I missing? Or, is this scheme possible at all?

Comment: Hi again! The 'No such file or directory' problem was caused by player.py having Windows instead of Linux line endings. I changed them and the problem was gone. But this did not solve the main situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of the main script and things began to run ok. I have no idea why though. Hope this be eventually of use to anyone.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark to the left.  This will let others learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Tested your sample application and they work fine for me, you don't need the glib mainloop invocation in the imported player.py though

Comment: Hi Christian, and thanks. I commented out the glib mainloop line in player.py and it run for a couple of seconds only (possibly connecting to the uri) and ended. Running the main script produced the same results as before.